# How Variance becomes infinite

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, regularization, statistical-learning

The text is from [Introduction to statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/),  by James *et al.*,  page 203-204 The doubts are highlighted in bold. Please help me to understand this.

**p**-No. of Independent variables , **n**-No.of obs.

> If $p>n$, then there is no longer a unique least squares coefficient estimate: the variance is inﬁnite so the method cannot be used at all.

***(How does variance become infinite?)***

> By constraining or shrinking the estimated coefficients, we can often substantially reduce the variance at the cost of a negligible increase in bias.

***(What does constraining or shrinking the estimated coefficients mean?)***

> This can lead to substantial improvements in the accuracy with which we can predict the response for observations not used in model training.

***(How?)***

Comment: You don't refer to a book's authorship by the first name of the third author, but by the family names of the authors, or by the family name of the first author followed by *et al.* ("and others"), I will fix it for you.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-and-infinite-variance

Comment: Maybe you should reduce this question to only the first out of three? It would fit better in the format of the stackechange websites. Regarding the tradeoff bias-variance there are already many topics on this site anyway (and this would make your question a duplicate if it would not have been for that first question about the infinity).  For instance: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336433/bias-variance-tradeoff-math

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the infinite variance of the least-squares estimator for the regression coefficients in case $p>n$, the book is right, in the following sense. If $p\leqslant n$ and the true model of the data is the one you are considering, i.e.
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \ldots + \beta_{p-1} x_{p-1,i} + \varepsilon_i
$$
for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and all $\varepsilon_i$ are independent and normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, then it can be shown that the column vector of least-squares estimates for $\beta_j$ ($j=0,\ldots,p-1$) has a multivariate normal distribution. That is, 
$$
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \sim \text{N}(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2(\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x})^{-1})
$$
with $\boldsymbol{\beta}=\left[\matrix{\beta_0\\ \beta_1\\ \vdots \\ \beta_{p-1}}\right]$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}=\left[\matrix{\hat{\beta_0}\\ \hat{\beta_1}\\ \vdots \\ \hat{\beta_{p-1}}}\right]$ and the design matrix $\boldsymbol{x} = \left[\matrix{1 & x_{11} & \cdots & x_{p-1,1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\ 1 & x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{p-1,n}}\right]$.
So the coefficient estimates have the true coefficients as their mean, which is good news because that makes these estimates $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ unbiased.

However, the main point here is that the Gram matrix $\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x}$ is not always invertible, in which case its inverse does not exist, or, as the book says "is infinite". That is just like the number $1/0$ is "infinite" or does not exist. In that situation, the estimates $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ are not unique, there are *many* values which minimise the sum of squares of the residuals.

If $p>n$ the columns of the design matrix $\boldsymbol{x}$ necessarily become linearly dependent and the Gram matrix $\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x}$ will not have full rank. That means its inverse does not exist (or is infinite), and neither does the variance of $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$.

Comment: The inverse exist if p>n so the least square estimator exist as well




Ref:-
[1] Mculloch and Searle. Generalized, Linear, and Mixed Models. Wiley, 2001.

Comment: The inverse of $\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x}$ does not exist if $\boldsymbol{x}$ is not of full column rank, which always is the case if $p>n$. The book by Searle correctly suggests that you can always use the *generalised* inverse of $\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{x}$ which does not require $\boldsymbol{x}$ to be of full column rank. That will give you a particular least-square solution among many. But, "It is misleading and in most cases quite wrong for (this solution) to be termed an estimator, particularly an estimator of ($\boldsymbol{\beta}$)" (Searle, 1997, "Linear Models", Wiley, p 169).

Comment: Could it be that the writers have been mixing up terms and did not mean to say that the *variance* is infinite (which of course makes no sense because the invers of $X^TX$ does not even exits). But maybe they meant to say that the solution *possibilities* are infinite.