# Is the mean (Bayesian) posterior estimate of $\theta$ a (Frequentist) unbiased estimator of $\theta$?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, bias, unbiased-estimator, frequentist

I am wondering about the different ways that Bayesian and Frequentist statistic connect with each other.

I recalled that the Maximum Likelihood estimate of a parameter $\theta$ is [not necessarily an unbiased estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/252129/7224) of that parameter.

That made me wonder: Is the Mean Posterior estimate of $\theta$ an unbiased estimator?

That is,

> Does $\phi(x)=E(\theta\mid x)$, imply $E(\phi(x)\mid\theta)=\theta$?

Note that this is indeed a meaningful question, since $\phi(x)$, while it is a Bayesian estimator, is simply a function from the data to the real line and so can also be seen as a classical frequentist estimator.

If this question cannot be answered in general, **please assume the prior is uniform.**

If not, is there some other Bayesian estimator (i.e. a function from the posterior to $\mathbb R$) that is always an unbiased estimator in the frequentist sense?

Comment: Maybe you meant "posterior mean" rather than "mean posterior".

Comment: The posterior mean is biased in favor of values having a higher prior probability.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Question: what's the difference between "posterior mean" and "mean posterior"?

Comment: @flow2k : There's no such thing as "mean posterior" as far as I know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a meaningful question which answer is well-known: when using a proper prior $\pi$ on $\theta$, the posterior mean $\delta^\pi(x) = \mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]$ cannot be unbiased. As otherwise [the integrated Bayes risk would be zero](https://www.isye.gatech.edu/%7Ebrani/isyebayes/bank/handout7.pdf):
\begin{align*}
r(\pi; \delta^\pi) &= \overbrace{\mathbb{E}^\pi\{\underbrace{\mathbb{E}^X[(\delta^\pi(X)-\theta)^2|\theta]}_{\text{exp. under likelihood}}\}}^{\text{expectation under prior}}\\
&= \mathbb{E}^\pi\{\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)^2+\theta^2-2\delta^\pi(X)\theta|\theta]\}\\
&= \mathbb{E}^\pi\{\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)^2+\theta^2]|\theta\}-
\mathbb{E}^\pi\{\theta \mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)|\theta]\}-\overbrace{\mathbb{E}^X\{\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|X]\delta^\pi(X)\}}^{\text{exp. under marginal}}\\
&= \mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta^2]+\underbrace{\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)^2]}_{\text{exp. under marginal}}
-\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta^2]-\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)^2]\\
& = 0
\end{align*}
*[**Notations**:  $\mathbb{E}^X$ means that $X$ is the random variable to be integrated in this expectation, either under likelihood (conditional on $\theta$) or marginal (integrating out $\theta$) while $^π$ considers $θ$ to be the random variable to be integrated. Note that $\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)]$ is an integral wrt to the marginal, while  $\mathbb{E}^X[\delta^\pi(X)|\theta]$ is an integral wrt to the sampling distribution.]*

The argument does not extend to improper priors like the flat prior (which is not uniform!) since the integrated Bayes risk is infinite. Hence, *some* generalised Bayes estimators may turn out to be unbiased, as for instance the MLE in the Normal mean problem which is also a Bayes posterior expectation under the flat prior. (But there is no general property of unbiasedness for improper priors!)

> A side property of interest is that $\delta^\pi(x) =
>   \mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]$ is sufficient in a Bayesian sense, as
> $$\mathbb{E}^\pi\{\theta|\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]\}=\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]$$Conditioning
> upon $\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]$ is the same as conditioning on $x$ for
> estimating $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick question, what exactly does $E^X(\cdot)$ mean? does it mean $E(\cdot|X)$?

Comment: Ok. You say that this doesn't apply to flat priors. (why are flat priors not the same as uniform?). Does that mean that in the case of a flat prior, the result I'm looking for holds?

Comment: So this would depend on the specific distribution $p(x|\theta)$? Is there no unbiased estimator that is unbiased, regardless of the distribution?

Comment: That's right, but a bayesian estimator will take the correct distribution of $X$ into account, since it will be reflected in the posterior, correct? So thats why my thought was that maybe there is a bayesian estimator that works regardless of the distribution of $X$

Comment: If the prior is improper, there may be distributions on $X$ that lead to an improper posterior.

Comment: Note that this is question 4.7 in BDA3 (Gelman et al.) with solution here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/solutions3.pdf. I have a follow-up question, @Xi'an: suppose a proper normal prior with mean equal to the true mean, say mu0. Then the posterior mean is a weighted average of x-bar and mu0, which has expectation mu0 = the true mean. Yet the problem is not degenerate. What have I missed?

Comment: ..I guess the problem is "degenerate" in the sense that the true distribution of theta is degenerate, but not in the sense that the posterior mean is constant. Should we maybe clarify that this only holds when the assumed prior is the true distribution of theta?

Comment: @SheridanGrant: the "trüe mean" of the observable $\bar{x}$, $\mu_0$, is an unknown and hence varies within a range of possible. Unbiasedness addresses a frequentist property that must hold for _all_ values of $\mu_0$, not just _one_. In that sense it is impossible to centre the prior at $\mu_0$.

Comment: Question: what precisely does "$\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|x]$ cannot be unbiased" mean? Could I confirm this statement means $\mathbb{E}^X[\mathbb{E}^\pi[\theta|X]] \neq \theta$? That is, whether the expectation is over $X$ wrt to the estimator.

Comment: The statement "Cannot be unbiased" is unambiguous, it means that the posterior expectation cannot be an unbiased estimator, therefore that there exist $\theta$'s such that $\mathbb{E}^X_\theta[\mathbb{E}^\pi[\Theta|X]] \neq \theta$.

Comment: @Xi'an Just saw your comment, and I realized I conflated the symbols erroneously. In your expression, does the subscript $\theta$ of $\mathbb{E}$ refer to conditioning on the parameter being $\theta$?

Comment: The outer expectation is a frequentist one computed wrt the frequentist distribution of $X$ indexed/parameterised by $\theta$. This is why I used $\Theta$ as the inner variate, to stress the different meanings of $\theta$ as the actual parameter behind the data and as the random variable distributed from the posterior.