Can median or mode of the order statistics be obtained?
Suppose $X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n$ is a random sample of size $n$ from a continuous probability distribution with cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F(x)$ and probability density function (PDF) $f(x)$. Let $X_{(1:n)}\leq X_{(2:n)}\leq\cdots\leq X_{(n:n)}$ denote the corresponding order statistics. The PDF of the $r^{th}$ order statistics $X_{r:n}$ is given by;
$$f_{r:n}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}[F(x)]^{r-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-r}f(x)$$
and the corresponding $1^{st}$ order moment of $r^{th}$ order statistics is given by;
$$E(X_{r:n})=\mu_{r:n}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x[F(x)]^{r-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-r}f(x)dx$$
It has been shown that $\mu_{r:n}$ exists provided that $E(X)$ exists.
Now, in many distributions like Cauchy, log-t, and inverse Weibull, the finite moments do not exist. Can we obtain the median or mode of $X_{r:n}$ in such cases?
Note: A specific contextual problem regarding this question is asked in this post.

Although the thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124 concerns medians, it applies (in straightforward ways) to any order statistics.  Let us know whether you don't find your answer in the posts there.

$E(X)$ existing is a sufficient condition for $\mu_{r:n}$ existing, but far from necessary. For example, this paper works out $\mu_{r:n}$ for the Cauchy distribution, which exist except for $r=1$ and $r=n$:  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-3990-1_11

@whuber Much appreciated. Meanwhile, I've updated my question within the context of a specific problem. Hope it clears what type of answer I'm trying to find

@ThomasLumley Thank you. I'm aware of this result from the book of David and Nagaraja. I've updated my question from the perspective of a specific problem. Hope it clears what I'm actually trying to seek

The same thing in @ThomasLumley's comment has been covered in H. A. David's book (chapter 3) also.

Order statistics often have moments even when the underlying distribution has no moments. See for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/469085/ . Distributions that have no finite moments for any order statistic are described here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469236/ .

"when expectation is itself non-existent, even Monte Carlo will suffer. In such case, what are the alternative ways to measure the average test completion time?" This sounds weird, and translates into the question: ”What are ways the estimate the mean, if the mean is not existent?". Did you mean ”What are alternative ways to describe a distribution, if the mean is not existent?" or did you mean  ”What are alternative ways to estimate/compute the mean of an order distribution, if the mean of the underlying distribution is not existent?".

@SextusEmpiricus I meant what are the alternative ways to compute a summary measure (be it mean, median or mode) of the order statistic when the mean of the underlying distribution as well as the order distribution does not exist. For instance, Cauchy order statistics have finite expectations except for minimum and maximum order statistics. Are the other measures of central tendency can be calculated for those two?

@DevD the median always exists.

Median
The cdf and pdf of continuous order statistics can be written algebraically in terms of the cdf and pdf of the original variables.
The median of an order statistic for a continuous distribution can be obtained from the median of the corresponding order statistic in the standard uniform case by transformation, noting that a continuous cdf and its inverse is a monotonic increasing (and thereby order-preserving) transformation; if half one set of values are $\leq m$ then if you transform them by a monotonic transformation $t$, half the transformed values are $\leq t(m)$.
Uniform order statistics are beta distributed, so the median of the distribution won't be in 'closed form' but it's easy enough to calculate if you can evaluate the inverse cdf of $X$.
Specifically we have:
$U_{k:n} \sim B(k,n+1-k)$
and
$U_{k:n}=F_X(X_{k:n})$.
This last equation is a fairly simple consequence of the fact that $U=F_X(X)$ is uniform. If a collection of $X_i$ values are in some order, the corresponding $U_i$ values are in that order and since $P(X_i<x)=P(U_i<F_X(x))$ the corresponding order statistics have the same relationship.
So the median of $X_{k:n}$ can be obtained by transforming that for $U_{k:n}$ by $F^{-1}$.
Casella and Berger[1] offer a proof of the cdf of an order statistic for continuous $X$ and obtain the density by differentiation (this is the one discussed in the Wikipedia page).
That the density of a uniform order statistic would be beta can be motivated readily; e.g. consider that you have a collection of independent standard uniform variates $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$.  Consider the probability that the $i$th order statistic $U_{i:n}$ is in the interval $(u,u+du)$. You need $i-1$ values to its left and $n-i$ values to its right. Which of the independent $U$'s is the one within the interval is a choice among $n$ possibilities, you need $i-1$ of the remaining $n-1$ to the left of it and the remainder to the right. So the probability of all of these events is ${{n-1}\choose{i-1}} F_U(u)^{i-1} \times (1-F_U(u))^{n-i} \times n f_U(u)$ for $0<u<1$. Now $F_U$ is just the identity in this interval and $f_U$ is $1$ in the interval, so we get: $f(u)du=n{{n-1}\choose{i-1}} u^{i-1}(1-u)^{n-i} du, \, 0<u<1$, which (dropping the $du$s) is the required density. The result for a general $X$ can either be obtained by the same form of argument (e.g. see Blitzstein & Hwang[2]), or by transformation from $U$.
Of course if you accept the density in your question as a given, we can directly write down the uniform case.
Example
Consider the fifth order statistic in a sample of size seven. We begin with the uniform. As indicated, it's distributed as a $\operatorname{Beta}(5,3)$, and so its median is (using the inverse cdf of that beta, in R):
 qbeta(.5,5,3)
[1] 0.6358839

(This is readily checked by simulation, by the way, always a good idea as it's easy to make small errors along the way.)
If you don't have a beta inverse cdf or equivalent (such as the inverse cdf for an F-distribution), then when $\min(i, n+1-i)$ is large, $\frac{i-\frac13}{n+\frac13}$ is a very good approximation to the median. Note that in our small example, finding the median exactly requires finding the real zero of a 7th degree polynomial. Even in this case, where $\min(i, n+1-i)$ is merely $3$, the approximation is fairly accurate, having a relative error of less that $0.1\%$ (the value in row 5):
> i <- 1:7
> cbind(med=qbeta(.5,i,8-i),Blom=ppoints(7,1/3))
            med       Blom
[1,] 0.09427634 0.09090909
[2,] 0.22848996 0.22727273
[3,] 0.36411609 0.36363636
[4,] 0.50000000 0.50000000
[5,] 0.63588391 0.63636364
[6,] 0.77151004 0.77272727
[7,] 0.90572366 0.90909091

Now we can directly convert to a standard Cauchy (say) from a uniform by transforming that result by the inverse cdf of the Cauchy (if you transform Cauchy variates by their cdf $F_X(X)$, you get uniforms, which we just worked out, and now we are transforming the result for the fifth-largest of them back):
> qcauchy(qbeta(.5,5,3))
[1] 0.4548645 

The same strategy works for any other quantile. For example, if you wanted say the 75th percentile of the distribution of the 5th largest of 7 standard Cauchy variates:
> qcauchy(qbeta(.75,5,3))
[1] 0.9808698

Mode
Since the density of $X_{k:n}$ can be written algebraically, 'the mode' (in scare quotes because there are a number of issues that we need to address for the phrase the mode to make sense and more to readily identify it) may be doable either numerically or perhaps algebraically.
Keeping in mind the usual caveats for trying to find maxima, of course. For example, there might  be multiple local  modes.
The density function might not be differentiable  everywhere and/or modes might not be at turning points, etc.
Note that we cannot simply use transformation from the uniform case here (quantiles are equivariant to monotonic-increasing transformations but modes are not), we must work with the density of $X_{k:n}$ directly in this case.
Let's try the same Cauchy example as before, but attempt to identify the mode instead - fortunately, in this case there is one to look for, the unique local maximum is a global maximum, it's at a turning point, and we can find it numerically. I haven't even attempted to solve it algebraically but perhaps that's doable. You  might try simplifying the derivative of the density and proceed with root-finding from there, but in this case I just supplied $-\log(f)$ to an optimizer and simply used numerical derivatives:
f <- function(x) -(4*pcauchy(x,log=TRUE) + dcauchy(x,log=TRUE) 
  + 2*pcauchy(x,lower.tail=FALSE,log=TRUE))
optim(1,f,method="Brent",lower=0,upper=2) 
$par
[1] 0.2963231

This agrees closely with the apparent location of the mode of of the density given above, and with the apparent mode of a histogram of simulated values of the given order statistic from a standard Cauchy:

It would be a relatively straightforward matter to generalize these sorts of functions, but as always with optimization (or root-finding for that matter), you must exercise a degree of care about it. Optimization is very often not nearly this neat.

[1]: Casella, George and Berger, Roger (2002), Statistical Inference (2nd ed.)
[2]: Blitzstein, Joseph K. and Hwang, Jessica (2019),
Introduction to Probability (2nd ed.)

Can you please provide any references where I can get the details?

Not clear what specific details you seek, sorry, but the wikipedia article on order statistics, along with the one on the probability integral transform should cover it. It comes with references. If you can highlight what specifics you need more on I can perhaps explain in more detail. I might add an example later

For example the part about the uniform order statistics being beta distributed can be found in Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference, but it is a pretty standard result and can be found in numerous texts on probability or mathematical statistics.

I've added some discussion and examples

Thank you for this elaborate discussion. It helped broaden my understanding a lot about the problem. In the meantime, I've updated my question within the context of a specific problem. Waiting to hear your inputs.

I'm not keen on questions that are moving targets. I answered the question as it stood at the time I started to answer it, in detail. That original question asked for a very different kind of response to the one you're now asking for an answer to.  That changed question is not merely clarification of the question that was, but a fundamentally different kind of question. I think to answer both here would make my post considerably less focused (and less useful to others) than it presently is.

I understand. Any answers to my original question was enough to understand my problem for me, I just gave a specific problem I was thinking about, beause I've seen very little discussion on the different summary measures of the order statistics apart from the Expectation. I was curious about what can we do when the expectation fails to summarize the order statistics.

It should work as a post of its own, I think, if suitably framed. If you want to link back to this one for added context, you could do that.

To do that, copy paste the new parts (and edit to add context) and revert the present question.

Are you saying I should keep this question as it was, and ask a new question with the edits and context? And link that question to this one?

Yes, that's my suggestion. The new question would not repeat the questions answered here, just the new ones plus as much context from here as needed to make the question answerable. It's not required that it link here; that's only something to do if that makes it clearer or more convenient for people to understand the new question. (Note that it's possible to revert a question to an earlier edit.)

I've reverted the question to its original version, and posted another question with the contexts and edits. Hope this helps.
