# What distributions have an undefined mean but are not symmetric?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

What distributions have an undefined mean but are not symmetric?

I'm looking for a probability distribution function (and CDF) for which the mean is undefined, but not symmetric like Cauchy, but a positive, continuous probability distribution with infinite mean and with a maximum density away from zero -- shaped like Poisson with a "hump".

I think a fat tail to positive infinity should work for an undefined mean, but what distributions are like that?

Comment: A Poisson random variable has finite maximum value? And can take on values ABOVE zero only?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but your language is a little bit confusing (you can see that @jld and I each interpreted it differently). Can you clarify? (I think by "like a Poisson" you just mean "defined on the non-negative reals with a maximum >0" ?)

Comment: Apologies! Yes, I mean shaped like Poisson, where there's a "hump" where the maximum density is, greater than 0. Like you say, "positive, continuous probability distribution with infinite mean and with a maximum density away from zero"

Comment: I updated my question with your language -- please feel free to edit it more.

Comment: Cauchy + positive constant, truncated at zero?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am guessing that you are looking for a *positive*, continuous probability distribution with infinite mean and with a maximum density away from zero.

I thought that by analogy with a Gamma distribution ($p(x) \propto x^a \exp(-x) \, dx$), we could try something with a rational (polynomial) rather than an exponential tail. After a little bit of lazy R and Python (sympy) experimentation, I came up with

$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\cdot \pi/9} \cdot \frac{x}{1+x^3} \, dx
$$

(I initially tried $p(x) \propto x/(1+x^2)$, but its integral diverges.) $\int_0^\infty p(x) \, dx$ is 1, as required, and $\int_0^\infty x p(x) \, dx$ diverges.

I don't know if this distribution has a name/literature associated with it.

The CDF is available in closed form but is pretty horrible ... (see Python code below ...)

$$
3 \sqrt{3} \left(- \frac{\log{\left(X + 1 \right)}}{6 \pi} + \frac{\log{\left(X^{2} - X + 1 \right)}}{12 \pi} + \frac{\sqrt{3} \operatorname{atan}{\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{3} X}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \right)}}{6 \pi}\right) + \frac{1}{4}
$$

Without actually trying anything, I would guess that distributions of the form $x^a/(1+x^{a+2})$ will generally have these properties (but the computations will get progressively nastier). Someone with more analysis skills could probably prove a bunch of things.

---

An extremely knowledgeable colleague identified this as **almost** the same as a "Beta-Type 2 (m=2/3,n=1/3)" distribution (a Beta-Type 2 distribution has a term of the form $(1+x)^n$ in the denominator rather than the $1+x^n$ given above). You might want to use the Beta-Type 2 instead of my version; since you know what it's called you can search for useful code, or literature on its properties (e.g. [here](https://vrcacademy.com/tutorials/beta-type2-distribution/) or [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/gamlss.dist/man/GB2.html) or McDonald et al 2013), or cite it in a paper: "Beta-Type 2" sounds so much better than "a distribution that some guy on CrossValidated made up".

> ... the Beta-Type 2 family with its density as

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\textrm{Beta}(m,n)} \frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}
$$

> over the support $(0,\infty)$

> It is evident that if $m$ is chosen to be > 1, the mode will be away from 0. Also, if $n$ is chosen to be $\leq 1$, then the mean will be infinite.  This family will produce [an] uncountable number of models with the property you are looking for.
> ... If you set $Y=X^3$ in your model, then it becomes a Beta-Type 2 $(m=2/3,n=1/3)$ and you can see that this fits the description I have given above.

They also identified the name of @ThomasLumley's contribution:

> ... it is called power gamma model or exponential-gamma model.

---

McDonald, James B., Jeff Sorensen, and Patrick A. Turley. “Skewness and Kurtosis Properties of Income Distribution Models.” Review of Income and Wealth 59, no. 2 (2013): 360–74. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1475-4991.2011.00478.x.

---

[image: curve of fat-tailed prob dist]

R code:

```r
f <- function(x) 1/(2*sqrt(3)*pi/9)*x/(1+x^3)
integrate(f, 0, Inf) ## 1 with absolute error < 4e-07
curve(f, from=0, to=10)
```

Python code (because I'm too lazy to integrate):

```
from sympy import *
x, n, N = symbols('x,n,N')
n=integrate(x/(1+x**3), (x, 0, oo))    ## 2*sqrt(3)*pi/9
integrate(x**2/(1+x**3), (x, 0, oo)) ## infinite mean
cdf = integrate(1/n*x/(1+x**3), (x, 0, X))
print(latex(cdf))
```

Comment: Like you mention, 1/1.11 * x ^ 2 / (x ^ 4 + 1) is interesting because it puts the maximum right with x=1 at approx. 0.5 (also thanks, Wolfram Alpha!)

Comment: +1 but I feel betrayed seeing you using Python.

Comment: This distribution is the Bolker distribution. ;-)

Comment: +1 I called it the "Bolker Distribution" in my code ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 8):

If $X$ comes from Gamma distribution with pdf
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}x^{k-1}e^{-x}$$
then $E[\exp(tX)]$ (the moment-generating function) exists only for $t<1$,
so $Z=\exp(X)$ (or even $Z-1$) is a strictly positive random variable without a finite mean.  For $k>1$ the mode is not at the lower limit

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a try! Your language "mode is not at the lower limit" much is better than my calling it a "hump" ;)

Answer (score 7):

Pareto distribution with density
$$
   f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha m^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} &,  x\ge m \\
                         0 &, x<m \end{cases}
$$
for some parameters $m>0, \alpha>0$. When $\alpha > 1 $ the expectation exists and is given by $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\cdot m$. When $\alpha \le 1$ the expectation do not exist, or as we say, it is infinite, because the integral defining it diverges to infinity.

Details in my answer at [What is the difference between finite and infinite variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-and-infinite-variance/100161)

Comment: That does have a mode away from zero, but it is at $m$, the minimum value of the support, so more of a shift than a hump

Answer (score 4):

I'll focus on continuous RVs. Let $X$ be a RV supported on $\mathbb R$ with density $f$.

If $X \geq 0$ a.s. (or $X\leq0$ a.s.) then the mean is well-defined, it's just $+\infty$ (or $-\infty$ if negative). This is just like how a sum of non-negative things always converges, it just might converge to $+\infty$. An example of this is the folded Cauchy distribution. In order to have an undefined mean we need $X$ to take both positive and negative values, and the mean on either set of values need to be infinite so that there's no overall mean.

Here's an example: take
$$
f(x) \propto \begin{cases}
\frac 1{(x-1)^2+1} & x < 1 \\
\frac 1{(x-1)^{3/2}+1} & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\text EX = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,\text dx \propto \int_{-\infty}^1 \frac{x}{(x-1)^2+1}\,\text dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^{3/2}+1}\,\text dx  = -\infty + \infty
$$
and this is undefined. I'm just combining two different tails where both are integrable but neither has a finite first moment. I'm also shifting it over to get the mode away from zero.

Comment: That's an interesting wrinkle -- I didn't know about converging on +infinity, but that certainly works as well

Comment: Couldn't you work out the mean by calculating one minus the other?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: both halves have divergent integrals, so subtracting the results will be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

A [non-central F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution) with $\nu_1=\nu_2=2$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality shape parameter $\lambda=3$ has support on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and looks like it satisfies all your requirements. Beta functions and Gamma functions have been expanded to put it in this very simple form:

$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{3}{2 x+2}} (5 x+2)}{2 (x+1)^3}, \ x\ge0
$$
The CDF is very simple too:
$$
F(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{3}{2 x+2}} x}{x+1}
$$
We have the following:
$$
\int^\infty_0{f(x)\ \text{d}x} = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{3}{2 (x+1)}} x}{x+1}=1
$$
The mean doesn't exist when $\nu_2\leq2$, and neither does the variance when $\nu_2\leq4$ which is our case above.

The mode appears at $x=(-7 + 3 \sqrt{41})/40\approx0.305$ so it has a maximum density beyond $0$.

[image: fratio distribution]

Comment: Nice! I'll try this one!

Answer (score 1):

One of the Pareto distributions:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X>x) = \frac 1 x \text{ for }x\ge1. \\[8pt]
& \Pr(X\in A) = \int_A \frac{dx}{x^2} \text{ for } A\subseteq (1,+\infty).
\end{align}

Comment: Like kjetil b halvorsen's example, that has a mode at $1$ which is the minimum of the support, more of a shift than a hump.

Answer (score 0):

The St. Petersburg distribution:
$$
\Pr(X= 2^n) = \frac 1 {2^{n+1}} \text{ for } n = 0,1,2,3,\ldots
$$

Comment: The OP is looking for a continuous probability distribution with a "hump" (mode not at the minimum value). I think this fails both criteria.